# How not to repeat the media queries in the CSS?

Tags: css, performance, responsive-design, sass, media-queries

Using SASS, I can do this

```
.foo {
  width: 100%;
  @media (max-width: 1200px) {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.foo {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .foo {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```

Ok, but I also have this code compiled:

```
.bar {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .bar {
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
}
```

Note that the `@media (max-width: 1200px)` are repeated and will be repeated throughout the code many times... So, how to gathers the equal media queries in the same place? 
Like this:

```
.foo {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .foo {
    width: 1000px;
  }
  .bar {
    padding: 50px 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think SASS can do this alone. I would look into integrating either grunt or gulp in your workflow, and using a task like https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-combine-media-queries or https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-combine-media-queries to automate this for you.

Comment: Also, according to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626174/is-there-an-advantage-in-grouping-css-media-queries-together/15643765#15643765) the performance impact of the repeated media queries is minimal.

Comment: You could also use the `css-condense` module or the `grunt-cssc` (just a grunt wrapper for the module mentioned)